# Why does this boost bind non-static member function fail?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind

Why does the following compiles i.e. passing a free function as parameter with the right signature:

```
inline double free_adapter_f(unsigned n, const double *x, double *grad, void *d) {
    return 0.0;
}

nlopt::opt opt(nlopt::LN_NELDERMEAD, X.size());
opt.set_min_objective(free_adapter_f, NULL);
```

whereas this other doesn't compile i.e. passing the result of `boost::bind` a class member function with the same signature:

```
template<class Space, class Solution, class Oracle>
inline double NelderMead<Space, Solution, Oracle>::adapter_f(unsigned n, const double *x, double *grad, void *d) {
    return 0.0;
}

nlopt::opt opt(nlopt::LN_NELDERMEAD, X.size());      
opt.set_min_objective(boost::bind(&NelderMead::adapter_f, this, ::_1, ::_2, ::_3, ::_4), NULL);
```

The error message is the following:

```
nelder_mead.h(98): error: no instance of overloaded function "nlopt::opt::set_min_objective" matches the argument list
    argument types are: (boost::_bi::bind_t<double, boost::_mfi::mf4<double,     NelderMead<TestSpace, VectorXd, oracle_f>, unsigned int, const double *, double *, void *>, boost::_bi::list5<boost::_bi::value<NelderMead<TestSpace, VectorXd, oracle_f> *>, boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2>, boost::arg<3>, boost::arg<4>>>, long)
        object type is: nlopt::opt
opt.set_min_objective(boost::bind(&NelderMead::adapter_f, this, ::_1, ::_2, ::_3, ::_4), NULL);
```

UPDATE: the overloaded `set_min_objective` are:

```
 typedef double (*func)(unsigned n, const double *x, double *grad, void *f_data);
 typedef double (*vfunc)(const std::vector<double> &x, std::vector<double> &grad, void *f_data);
 void set_min_objective(func f, void *f_data);
 void set_min_objective(vfunc vf, void *f_data);
```

Comment: ANd what are the available overloads of `set_min_objective`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example, which demonstrates your problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

namespace g
{
  typedef int (*func)(int a, int b, int c);

  void bar(func f)
  {
    std::cout << "g::bar:: called" << (*f)(10, 20, 30) << std::endl;
  }

  // Disable the over load below and you will get the same error
  void bar(boost::function<int(int, int, int)> f)
  {
    std::cout << "g::bar:: called" << f(10, 20, 30) << std::endl;
  } 
}

template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
class foo
{

public:

  int bar(int a, int b, int c) const
  { return a + b + c; }

  void call()
  {
    g::bar(boost::bind(&foo::bar, this, ::_1, ::_2, ::_3));
  }
};

int main(void)
{
  foo<int, double, int> f;
  f.call();
  return 0;
}
```

Main reason is that `boost::function<>` is not *convertible* to a function pointer, so you need to provide an overload which accepts this (as above.)

EDIT: just to clarify things a little further. `boost::bind()` does *not* explicitly return a `boost::function<>`, however, the object it returns can be stored in the correct instantiation of `boost::function<>`, in the above case, the correct instantiation is `boost::function<int(int, int, int)>`.

Normally you would only need to resort to storing it in a `boost::function` if you were interested in propagating it (without a template) or storing it for later use. In this case, as you are passing the result of the `bind()`, you need to have the correct overload to accept the returned object from `boost::bind()`, and the easiest way to do this without resorting to templates is to accept a `boost::function` (as above.)

Normally, I'm pragmatic, so I would resort to this (without knowing what you are wanting to do with `f`) where possible.

```
template <typename F>
double set_min_objective(F f, ...)
{
}
```

Then you are agnostic, of course purists will have other opinions.

NOTE: A nice thing with `boost::function<>` is that you can store a non-member function pointer in one too (as long as the signature matches.) So in reality you only need a version of your function which accepts the correct `boost::function<>` and it will work in both cases (member function with `boost::bind()` and non-member function.)

**EDIT2:** Okay, given the additional information, you have to resort to the following mechanism, you need to have a non-member function of your class, which will then delegate to the member function, for example:

```
<>
class NelderMead
{

static double delegate_f(unsigned n, const double *x, double *grad, void *f_data)
{
  // I'm assuming here the frame work passed you whatever you gave in f_data
  NelderMead* inst = reinterpret_cast<NelderMead*>(f_data);
  return inst->adapter_f(n, x, grad);
}

double adapter_f(unsigned n, const double *x, double *grad)
{
}

void set()
{
  nlopt::opt opt(nlopt::LN_NELDERMEAD, X.size());      
  opt.set_min_objective(delegate_f, this); //<-- here pass the instance as the additional data
}

};
```

This is a typical pattern employed by third-party libraries which are meant to be agnostic to user code.

Comment: `boost::bind` does not return a `boost::function` so it's not immediately obvious what `boost::function` has to do with anything. If you explained that the right specialization of `boost::function` can store the object returned by `boost::bind` (among other things) that might help.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, yip, editing...

Comment: `set_min_objective` belongs to a third party library NLopt which I'd prefer not to modify. In fact, I am trying to adapt two different optimization oracle function interfaces so I can use my framework and be able to plugin this external library.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define set_min_objective which accepts boost::function as first parameter:

```
 typedef boost::function<double (unsigned n, const double *x, double *grad, void *f_data)> func_t;
 ...
 void set_min_objective(func_t, void*);
 ...
```

another thing - you'd better not to use NULL

Comment: Aha, okay, you've said the same thing, +1, I'll leave my answer as up as it has the SSCCE which demonstrates this.

Comment: I can't do that because `set_min_objective` belongs to a third party library that I prefer not to modify. In fact this code is an attempt to adapt the signature of my optimizer framework to this third party library NLOpt.

Comment: @GiovanniAzua in this case the only thing that you can do is to define function which adapts your NelderMead::adapter_f. This is ugly but works: `NelderMead instance; double nelder_mead_adapter_f(unsigned n, const double *x, double *grad, void *d) { return instance.adapter_f(n, x, grad, d); }` so you can pass this free function to NLOpt interface.

Comment: Exactly I can't live with static singleton instances for this. I need to be able to handle it at instance level.

Answer (score 0):

Both overloads of `set_min_objective` expect a pointer-to-function as the first parameter, but the object returned by `boost::bind` is not a pointer-to-function, it's a function object.

`boost::bind` returns a function object that stores the target function and any bound arguments, it doesn't synthesize a function and return a pointer to it, or magically turn a pointer-to-member-function into a pointer-to-function. That would be magic.